NetSuite to Salesforce Opportunity / OpportunityLineItem Currency Mapping
We're running into an odd issue with our Celigo integration between Salesforce and NetSuite.
We have a process to generate renewals from NetSuite into Salesforce, but we're having issues with Currency coming over as expected.
For example, we'll pass the CurrencyISO value (GBP in this case) to the Salesforce renewal Opportunity, and Salesforce will default the currency to USD.
I have a hunch that this has something to do with our Pricebooks / Products. The Currency code is not being mapped to the OpportunityLineItems. If the Product currency isn't mapped, does that override the Opportunity currency?

do you have pricebook entries (PBE) for each Product / Currency combination in SFDC?  While I don't know anything about the Celigo integration, the approach would be for it to look for the PBE matching the SKU and currency and assign that to the OpportunityLineItem, provided that the Opportunity Currency is also set to the currency
